# What's wrong with my calculation of the expectation of the Laplace distribution?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, distributions

```
f2[x_, mu2_, sigma2_] =  1/Sqrt[2*sigma2^2]*Exp[-Sqrt[2]*Abs[(x - mu2)/sigma2]]

Integrate[x*f2[x, mu, sigma], {x, -Infinity, Infinity},  Assumptions -> sigma > 0]
```

I am pretty sure that the above should produce `mu`, but it doesn't. What's wrong with it? I did the same thing in Sage, and it worked all right.

Comment: Just who is "Lacplac"?

Comment: @J.M. A friend of mine http://www.gador.com.ar/?cont=prod&id=552

Comment: @bel, your friend makes me sleepy.

Comment: @J.M. Sorry to spoil the joke with my edit, but I felt I had a duty to posterity.

Comment: @m_goldberg, no worries, and thanks. :) (Actually, I was hoping the OP himself might give an introduction to whoever The Great Mister Lacplac was, but oh well.)

Comment: FWIW, `Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] LaplaceDistribution[μ, β]] // FullSimplify`

Comment: @J.M. then `Mean@LaplaceDistribution[μ, β]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f2[x_, mu2_, sigma2_] := 1/Sqrt[2*sigma2^2]*Exp[-Sqrt[2]*Abs[(x - mu2)/sigma2]]

Integrate[x*f2[x, mu, h], {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
          Assumptions -> {Element[mu, Reals], h > 0}]

(*
  mu
*)
```

#### Edit

Let's make what he did wrong crystal clear to the OP.

1. Should have used `SetDelayed` (`:=`) rather than `Set` (`=`) when defining f2.
2. Needed to have an additional assumption that `mu` was a real number.

Comment: Complex Integral.. Anyway I don't see any reason to use ":=" instead of "=" in this case. "=" works fine.

Comment: @user6932. That's only because you haven't so far made any global assignments to `x`, `mu1` or `sigma2`. But you have a time bomb ticking away.

Answer (score 0):

One way to circumvent it is like this

```
f2[x_, mu2_, sigma2_] :=  
                    Piecewise[{{1/Sqrt[2*sigma2^2]*Exp[-Sqrt[2]*((x - mu2)/sigma2)], x - mu2 >= 0}, 
                               {1/Sqrt[2*sigma2^2]*Exp[-Sqrt[2]*((mu2 - x)/sigma2)], x - mu2 < 0}}]

Integrate[x*f2[x, mu, sigma], {x, -Infinity, Infinity},  Assumptions -> sigma > 0]

(*
  mu
*)
```